# How do I perform an effective array search in PHP when I'm looking for more than one key in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

Taking a dictionary as an example, let's say I've got the following array to catalog the pronunciations of a given word:

`$pronunciation["text"] = array("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon");`

`$pronunciation["definition"] = array(1, 2, NULL, NULL, 1);`

`text` contains the pronunciation that will be displayed to the user, while `definition` contains the ID for the definition in the list where that pronunciation applies.  If `definition` is `NULL`, it's not associated with any particular definition, and should be displayed elsewhere in the entry.

Now, if I try to do something like the following:

`$key = array_search(1, $pronunciation["definition"]);`

All I'll get is `0`, since that's the first key in `definition` that contains the value.  Likewise, substituting `NULL` returns `3`, however both of these actually have another related key that I'm trying to fetch.

Is there a way to get it to return all related keys without having to resort to brute force methods such as a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

`array_keys($pronunciation["definition"],1)`

Comment: I do not know that `array_keys` extra parameter!

Comment: ^^ I just discovered it a few days ago :).

Comment: That's perfect!  Now I can just use a `foreach` loop to go through the limited set instead of re-running the whole array each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not a function that do that as you want. ***Edit:*** Nope, there is! See Jauzsika answer.
You have to use a `foreach` or a `for` loop.

```
function array_search_all($needle, $haystack) {
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($haystack as $k => $v) if ($v === $needle) $keys[] = $k;
    return $keys;
}
```

Call:

```
$keys = array_search_all(1, $pronunciation["definition"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wheter it's faster or not, but I think if there're a set of data which you have to search in, it's better to set up an array, where the data is the key.

```
$data["alpha"] = 1
$data["beta"] = 1
//...
```

All your *foreach* should be modified from

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
```

to

```
foreach ($data as $item => $value) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your arrays into a single array keyed on the text and using the definition as the value:

```
$pronunciation = array("alpha" => 1, 
                       "beta" => 2, 
                       "gamma" => NULL, 
                       "delta" => NULL, 
                       "epsilon" => 1);
```

Then use [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to build a subset of the values you need

```
$searchVal = 1;
$subset = array_filter($pronunciation,
                       create_function('$value', 'return $value == '.$searchVal.';')
                      );
var_dump($subset);
```